# Is it a good practice to use useMasterKey() in cloud code?

Tags: parse-platform

For security reasons we are planning to disable all write access to classes. Client applications (android and IOS sdks) will only have read-only access to the Parse data(classes)
Data stored in parse servers will be only modified by cloud functions. The cloud functions will call

`Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();`

We have come up with this solution because it is nearly impossible to hide parse application ids and parse client key from attackers/hackers.

So is this a good solution? Are there any drawbacks? Does "Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()" method have performance implications?

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty standard practice, you implement your own security in your Cloud Functions and use the master key.

In theory it might be more efficient using the master key as the Parse servers don't have to process the Roles/Users/ACLs at all when the master key is used. Of course you need to balance that with any extra check your security logic does.